# Create regex for cleansing company names java

Tags: java, regex

I want to cleanse company names by removing all the "LTD", "INC", etc.

I am new to regexes and I have searched for similar questions but none of them worked for me as they were in different syntax or did not fit with my problem.

I imported a CSV file with all known suffixes in the world as a basis for my refex. The content of the CSV looks like this:

```
...
co
commv
coop
corp
corporation
cpora
cpt
crl
cv
cvoa
cxa
da
...
```

Here is the code:

```java
// BS: Method which read the common company suffixes and creates a regex string

public String readCSVMapping() {
        String result = "";
        int i = 0;
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data/ofac/other/company_suffix_cln.csv"));) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                try (Scanner rowScanner = new Scanner(line)) {
                    rowScanner.useDelimiter(";");
                    while (rowScanner.hasNext()) {
                        if(i==0) {
                            result = result + rowScanner.next().toUpperCase();
                            i++;
                        }
                        else {
                            result = result + "|" + rowScanner.next().toUpperCase();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // BS: sort the string by length of string (descending)
        String[] results = result.split("\\|");
        Arrays.sort(results, (a,b)->b.length() - a.length());
        result = String.join("|", results);

        return result;
    }
```

Unfortunately, it also removes 'ba' from 'bank', which I do not want. I tried to add boundaries to my result string but that did not remove the suffixes at all.. Example:

`result = result +"|"+ "\\\b" + rowScanner.next().toUpperCase() + "\\\b";`

Thank you in advance!

Bas

Comment: Could you some examples? Few names/strings that work for you and few that don't.

Comment: Try `"\\b"` instead of `"\\\b"` (which is a backslash followed by a backspace).

Comment: Might be worth replacing your csv reading code here with some sample regex input/output code.

Comment: data/ofac/other/company_suffix_cln.csv share this file

Comment: Sorry of course, here's an example: ```"THE BANK OF SCOTLAND, LTD, INC., S.P.A."``` my code returns ```THE NK OF OTLAND```

Comment: @Schmidt88 will these values are always preceded by `,` ?

Comment: I edited the question to give some more understanding of the csv, thanks

Comment: @CodeManiac, no they aren't, they can also be seperated by a whitespace

Comment: why you removed `B` from `Bank` and `SC` from `SCOTLAND` ?

Comment: @Schmidt88 what i mean by my first comment is `THE BANK OF SCOTLAND, LTD, INC., S.P.A.` if you see all the abbreviations comes after the first comma, so if this is standard pattern you can simply take the values upto first `,`

Comment: @CodeManiac, yes, that would be nice but unfortunately, there is no pattern

Comment: @CodeManiac, 'BA' and 'SC' are a suffix from Norwegian and Poland respectively

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks I got it fixed now!

Comment: Why even use RegEx for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies but the answer was quite simple actually...

```java
if(i==0) {
    result = result + "\\b" + rowScanner.next().toUpperCase() + "\\b";
    i++;
}
else {
    result = result + "|" + "\\b" + rowScanner.next().toUpperCase() + "\\b";
}
```

It works now